# java: saving parts of String in multiple ArrayLists

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I have a String with different values, separated by ";" without a space. How can I save the first value until the ";" into the ArrayList part1, the second value into the next ArrayList and so on?

```
String line = "10,23;190,33;86,423;132,45";
ArrayList<Double> part1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Double> part2 = new ArrayList<>();
...
part1.add("10,23");
part2.add("190,33");
```

I tried the following function, but this does not work:

```
int index = line.indexOf(";");
part1.add(line.substring(0, index);
```

Comment: Why not use `String[] res = line.split(";");`? Not sure what you need to get in the end though.

Comment: Do you really need more than one ArrayList for this?

Comment: what I want to say is: `ArrayList<Double> part1.add("10,23");` cannot pass my eye compiler... I know you are making examples, however.... the syntax is so wrong, type is so wrong.....

Comment: If that line is part of a file and you like to save each column (like in a CSV file) into a dedicated arraylist, then you should ask *that* instead. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

If the idea is to have one List populated with Doubles from your String, you can do it in one line :

```
    List<Double> parts = Arrays.stream(line.split(";")).map(elem -> new Double(elem.replace(",", "."))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Of course you will have to deal with Exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want to parse the double values from the string.

Here is a code snippet, which should do what you require:

```
private static <S, T> void distributeValues(S[] sourceParts, Function<S, T> transformFunction, List<T> ... targetParts) {
  for (int i = 0; i < sourceParts.length; i++) {
    S part = sourceParts[i];
    targetParts[i].add(transformFunction.apply(part));
  }
}
```

A call to that method could look like:

```
distributeValues(line.split(";"), 
                   s -> Double.valueOf(s.replace(",", ".")), 
                   part1, part2, part3, part4);
```

This way you are free to choose, which lists you want to populate. You could even specify `part1, part2, part1, part2` if you require something like that.

A sample main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String line = "10,23;190,33;86,423;132,45";
  List<Double> part1 = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Double> part2 = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Double> part3 = new ArrayList<>();
  List<Double> part4 = new ArrayList<>();

  distributeValues(line.split(";"), s -> Double.valueOf(s.replace(",", ".")), part1, part2, part3, part4);

  System.out.println("part1 = " + part1);
  System.out.println("part2 = " + part2);
  System.out.println("part3 = " + part3);
  System.out.println("part4 = " + part4);
}
```

which prints:

```
part1 = [10.23]
part2 = [190.33]
part3 = [86.423]
part4 = [132.45]
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you do not really need multiple Arraylist. Just use one:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
line = line.replace(",", ".");
String[] tokens = line.split(";");

for(int x=0; x<list.size(); x++)
    list.add(Double.parseDouble(token[x]));
```

- So if your line has `"1.1;2,2;3,3;4.4;5.5"`
- tokens will store `"1.1"`, `"2.2"`, `"3.3"`, `"4.4"`, `"5.5"` as array of strings
- the strings will be parsed to double and store into the arraylist accordingly

Comment: While this may be right it does not fulfill his requirement of having multiple ArrayLists.

Comment: @PavneetSingh That depends on the format of your number. Some countries uses `,` instead of `.` as a decimal. In that case, you can replace all the `,` as `.` first.

Comment: @MuratK. I think it is rather obvious OP actually only wants 1 arraylist. He probably misunderstood the use of arraylist, hence wanted to use multiple lists.

Answer (score 0):

split method is the solution for this. It will split based on the delimiter and returns an array of substrings.

```
string[] subStrings = line.split(";");
```